# Yii ActiveRecord using scope with another scope

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

i want to use some scope if yii active record model in same model's another scope
see the following code, you will understand what i want to say?

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'avg_all'=>array(
            'select'=>array(
                'avg_fp_1'=>'AVG(CASE when t.fp_1>=0 then t.fp_1 ELSE NULL END)',
                'avg_fp_2'=>'AVG(CASE when t.fp_2>=0 then t.fp_1 ELSE NULL END)',
                'avg_fp_3'=>'AVG(CASE when t.fp_3>=0 then t.fp_1 ELSE NULL END)',
                'avg_fp_4'=>'AVG(CASE when t.fp_4>=0 then t.fp_1 ELSE NULL END)',
                'avg_fp_5'=>'AVG(CASE when t.fp_5>=0 then t.fp_1 ELSE NULL END)',
            ),
        ),
        'avg_feedback'=>array(
            'with'=>array('avg_all'),
            'select'=>array(
                'avg_feedback'=>'ROUND((avg_fp_1+avg_fp_2+avg_fp_3+avg_fp_4+avg_fp_5)/5,2)'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

main problem `'with'=>array('avg_all'),`

is it possible to use another scope inside a scope.

Comment: Please do not change the question in such a fundamental way. You can supply updates if there's a new aspect. But in your case you should have asked a new question instead. It would be good if you could undo your latest changes, to make the answer match your initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `scopes` instead of `with`.

```
'scopes' => array('avg_all'),
```